# Can an ember(-cli) app trigger window.onerror?

Tags: ember.js, error-handling

Is there any kind of javascript error that is not handled by [onerror](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#event_onerror) in an ember(-cli) application? In other terms, is there any need to add a handler to [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)?

In my tests I could not come up with any error that would no be handled by Ember's onerror. Syntax errors didn't get past ember-cli's build process.

Comment: You should handle `window.onerror` `Ember.onerror` and `Ember.RSVP.onerror`

Comment: Do you have any prove or example for why I should handle `window.onerror`?

Comment: There is not a real need to handle `Ember.RSVP.onerror` if you already handle `Ember.onerror`. See [the code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.2.2/packages/ember-runtime/lib/ext/rsvp.js#L71)

Comment: To me it semms that whole Ember run loop is wrapped in try catch, so application code errors should be 100% handled by this Ember.onerror. However I'm not sure that's why it's a comment. :)

Comment: There are thousands of potential errors which ember.onerror will not catch. Any error thrown before the app launches, any error outside the scope of the app (think 3rd party async), most network errors, most CSP errors, and any async error from your own code being executed outside the scope of ember.

Comment: It's interesting that `Ember.RSVP.onerror` falls back to `Ember.onerror`, I have not found this to be true in practice.

Answer (score 2):

EmberJS does an excellent job of containing errors that happen **within its boundaries**. Errors caused by your Ember code should all get funneled into the Ember-specific handler.

However, browser JavaScript is a complicated beast. Any JavaScript errors that happen **outside** of Ember would not be captured internally and may only be exposed by the global `window.onerror`. Some examples of these could include:

- Unbounded callbacks into native functions like `setTimeout` and `addEventListener`
- Non-ember JavaScript libraries and integrations, such as Stripe, Twitter, or Advertisements
- Browser-extension script that can interact with the DOM in unpredictable ways.

To get a complete picture of what is happening with your visitors, you should probably attach to both `Ember.onerror` **and** `window.onerror` and send the reports back to your logs. Even if you are not actively developing, browser changes can cause sudden bugs to appear in your application. Like [this webkit bug that caused ember to throw errors](https://trackjs.com/blog/tracked-attempted-assign-readonly-property-ios-8-typeerror/). There are good options to record errors automatically from Ember apps, like [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com/).

Disclosure: I am one of the founding developers of TrackJS, so I've debugged a lot of errors :)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I would not advise implementing a `window.onerror`, unless you have a strong reason to do so and you know what you may be doing.

To my knowledge all of Ember's `onerror` methods piggy-back on to `window.onerror` and overriding it has potential to override/disable all the error in your app.

Case in point,  I had an experience recently where i noticed that all my js errors stopped logging to console altogether.  The reason was that another developer in my team had bootstrapped into my index.html to inject a `<script>` tag which utilized `window.onerror` for some error reporting script.  The result was that overriding `window` litterally disabled all of ember's `onerror` becuase they work in a bubbling fashion.

I think if you do want to override `window.onerror` you need to ensure that it always returns `false` so that it does not prevent default error handling on the browser.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

I hope that helps clarify to some degree.

Answer (score -1):

Ember has a built in error event you can use in your routes

```
  actions: {
    error(error, transition) {
      if (error && error.status === 400) {
        //handle error
      }
    }
  }
```

More Info: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/